# Can dropbox pick up 2 folders on different locations on the same machine and sync under the same account?

Tags: windows-7, dropbox, file-sharing

I use dropbox and my main folder resides D: local drive on a win 7 machine. I have linked a linux machine's folders at Z:, I would like to have those folders to be included in my dropbox too. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

From Dropbox website: "Right now, Dropbox will only sync the files in your Dropbox folder."
https://www.dropbox.com/help/12

However, there are some ways to achieve it.

I would suggest, apart from moving the folder into your Dropbox folder and setting up a shortcut (Windows), alias (Mac OS X), or link (Linux) to access it from its former location (the solution proposed by Dropbox), to research on [symbolic links](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)

Other solutions are proposed [here](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/sync-other-folders).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dropboxifier](http://dropboxifier.codeplex.com/). It allows for symbolic links via a GUI. Remember that symbolic links are followed once. If you make changes, you'll have to exit out of Dropbox and start again if you want the symbolic link to be followed again.